# GNU autotools: cmake gui to configure conversion

Tags: c++, cmake, gnu, cmake-gui

So I have this cmake gui:
[image]

I can only partially translate that in to following cmd:

```
configure --prefix=/opt/systemc --enable-pthreads
```

How should I set CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE and CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD?

Comment: What is your goal? You know CMake and Autotools are two different build systems, right? If you just want to build from the terminal, you can do so with CMake too.

Comment: `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` is not what a project's **user** should set: It is a project itself which selects C++ standard according to needs of its sources. The same is about autotools. Concerning build/debug builds with autotools see e.g. [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553735/gnu-autotools-debug-release-targets).

Answer (score 0):

Everything can be set using the `-D` option. For your question:

```
cd /usr2/aswang/Downloads/systemc-2.3.3/build
cmake .. \
  -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
  -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=11 \
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/systemc \
  -DSystemC_TARGET_ARCH=linux64
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D